# ASP.NET multiple bind parameter

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to bind the parameters of an ASP.NET method with two different models as shown in below:

```
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,PatientLevel")] PatientEnt Patient,string ProgramMode, [Bind(Include = "PassportNumber,PassportIssueDate")]
        PatientsDetailsEnt PaientDetail)
```

The Model of the controller is PatientEnt which is binding correctly, but the PatientsDetails fields is not binding.

Comment: If you want to use two or model in same ActionResult Method in Controller you must have to create new model which contains both model objects and that model call in Both side controller and view. so finally you can use both model fields binding in one controller. Try this i hope your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You can merge tow Model to One in an other model and Use it;

Whish You bests, Heydar